# Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: WRITER

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, servlet-filters, jetty-9

This  warning shows  every time i  receive a redirect call from other server (call back is configured to get redirect with specific detail ) . After receiving i call one post call and  dispatch the request to my page.

The flow complete with exception warning  .

stack trace for the exception .

```
 doHandle:  (ServletHandler.java:624)
 org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request  processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: WRITER
at   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:973)
at  org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:848)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1772)
at com.full.util.DomainFilter.doFilter(DomainFilter.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:37)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:48)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:297)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.RpcConnection.handle(RpcConnection.java:202)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.RpcConnector.serviceRequest(RpcConnector.java:81)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:108)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest(JavaRuntime.java:680)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest(JavaRuntime.java:642)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:612)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$NullSandboxRequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:806)
at      com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:274)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WRITER
```

I am using java 8 with GAE (Google app engine) .The above warning does not show  if i switch back to java7 version .

Sample code

```
   @Override
   public String callBack(HttpServletRequest request,  HttpServletResponse response) {
    logger.info("inside callback method  Integration");

    try{
        logger.info("the request uri "+request.getQueryString());
         //data store call to get  more detail .

            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            String responseString = httpClient.post(accessUrl, headerMap, params);
            logger.info("the resposne String is " + responseString);
            Map<String, Object> responseMap = StringConverterUtil.stringToMap(responseString);
            logger.info("the quickBooks response string is " + responseMap);
            logger.info("the eventConfigObject is " + request.getSession().getAttribute("eventConfigObject"));
            request.getSession().setAttribute("isNoAccountFlag", true);
            if (responseMap != null && responseMap.containsKey("access_token")) {
                logger.info("the domain name is " + platform.getDomainName());
// save the detail on datastore 

                     request.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/authenticateSuccess.jsp?status=success").forward(request, response);
                     return null;
        }       
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        logger.log(Level.ERROR, e.toString(), e);
        try {
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/authenticateSuccess.jsp?status=failed").forward(request, response);
        } catch (ServletException e1) {
            logger.log(Level.ERROR, e.toString(), e);

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            logger.log(Level.ERROR, e.toString(), e);

    }

    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Did you follow the GAE Standard Java 7 to 8 Migration guide listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/migrating-to-java8)? Are you using Flex or Standard environment?

Comment: Also it seems that "StringConverterUtil.stirngToMap()" function is misspelled.

Comment: Thanks @Kenworth . Yes i am following the same documentation .We are using App engine standard  environment.